# Is there any research that challenges the standard definition of 'προορίζω' (predestine)?

Tags: greek, word-study

The definition of προορίζω in the Enhanced Strong's Lexicon is:

> 4309 Six occurrences; AV translates as “predestinate” four times,
>   “determine before” once, and “ordain” once. 1 to predetermine, decide
>   beforehand. 2 in the NT of God decreeing from eternity. 3 to
>   foreordain, appoint beforehand.

Is there any reliable, peer reviewed research that contradicts this definition?

Comment: This is an interesting answer, but do keep in mind that [Strong's is a concordance, not a lexicon, and generally free tools that use Strong's rely on outdated lexical resources](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/642/423). You may wish to reference what [a more recent (and more reliable) lexicon](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/642/423) says.

Comment: Please, forgive my ignorance, but I am honestly confused. You mean the book I have titled, "Enhanced Strong's Lexicon" is not in fact, a lexicon? Here is the product link:https://www.logos.com/product/181/enhanced-strongs-lexicon

Comment: that's correct, it says in the description on that link: "Strong's Numbers with Brown, Driver, Briggs and Thayer lexicons." The Hebrew lexicon is thus BDB and the Greek is Thayer's, which [I explain in this post.](http://meta.hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/642/423)

Comment: But it is a good question, because historically it did not always carry the Calvinist/fatalist sense of 'predetermine' from a historical perspective - but I need to find the source I read however long ago before I can answer.

Comment: Actually, I probably will not answer, because the plain meaning of the word is fine. It is moreso the Manichean-Gnostic-influenced doctrinal/theological positions that evolved in association with the word that were not inherent in its meaning. But the plain sense of the word has not changed, as John points out.

Comment: Check out http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Predestination#Church_Fathers_on_the_doctrine

Comment: This question is a little late, but is there a specific text this is related to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That seems unlikely. The word is clearly a compound of προ, which is equivalent to the English prefix "pre-", and ορίζω which [means](http://www.babylon.com/define/105/Greek-Dictionary.html):

> v. define, fix, designate, detail, determine, prescribe, set

As far as I can tell, this particular definition still applies to the word in modern Greek.

Comment: Yes it mean that but has nothing to do with Gnostic (Manichean) fatalism as Augustine falsely asserted.